# Not able to type text in the WYSIWYG editor using selenium ide

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

i am facing a problem to type text in the wysiwyg editor.
I have tried using the following code

```
storeEval
this.browserbot.findElement("class=wysihtml5-sandbox";).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML='test text';
MyVar
```

but its not working for me and one thing i would like to tell u that with firebug javascript console i am able to insert the text using the below javascript

```
tinyMCE.get("Id of the editor").setContent("Test TExt")
```

but this command is not working in selenium ide

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Did you actually put javascript code in a HTML list as text, or was that a formatting error in the body of this question?

Comment: its was a formatting error

Comment: So please, edit the body of the question. I did a first edit, but I'm not sure this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I've solution of your question. I'm also using this command.

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Enter your text here')</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```